# scrollIntoView() bugging on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, event-handling, js-scrollintoview

I am trying to achieve the effect where I can scroll jump from one to another div ID. Basically I scroll down on *div-1* and triggers an event on the scroll and jumps to *div-2* and vice versa. I was able to achieve it in vanilla JS. It's flickering on Chrome, but working smoothly on other browsers (except grandpa IE). Anyone knows what might be causing it, and what solution or alternate I can get?

```js
document.getElementById("scroll-div1").addEventListener("wheel", myFunction1);

function myFunction1() {
    document.getElementById("scroll-div1").addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    document.getElementById("scroll-div2").scrollIntoView();
  }
  else if (e.deltaY < 0) {
       window.scrollTo(0,0);
  }
});
} 

document.getElementById("scroll-div2").addEventListener("wheel", myFunction2);

function myFunction2() {
        document.getElementById("scroll-div2").addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    document.getElementById("scroll-div3").scrollIntoView();
  }
  else if (e.deltaY < 0) {
       window.scrollTo(0,0);
  }
});
} 

document.getElementById("scroll-div3").addEventListener("wheel", myFunction3);

function myFunction3() {
        document.getElementById("scroll-div3").addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
    if (e.deltaY < 0) {
       document.getElementById("scroll-div2").scrollIntoView();
  }
});
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll-div1" style="height: 768px; overflow: auto;">
<p>This is div 1</p>
</div>
<div id="scroll-div2" style="height: 768px">
<p>This is div 2</p>
</div>
<div id="scroll-div3" style="height: 768px">
<p>This is div 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

So I tried to also use jQuery with various methods and seems like the issue is with browsers supporting scrolling synchronously/asynchronously. In this case, Chrome seems to have the ***asynchronous*** scrolling, which lags the scrolling callbacks. So for now, in September 2018, I am unable to give the certain effect I was looking for and wait for some improvements in future.

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Scroll-linked_effects

Comment: as of now, have you encountered any solution or possible approaches to the problem?

Comment: Haven't unfortunately. If you get some thing, let us know!

Comment: Hey @TayeabaMila , great explanation! I am facing the same thing and I wonder if you have discovered anything by now. Cheers =)

And what about you @agostos?